# get page_id in ajax to function in functions.php

Tags: functions, ajax

Im loading "read more"-content via ajax and json. This works global for all pages. But I need the extra-content only from the current page Im viewing. Now I want to pass the page_id into my function but cant get it work. I tried setting the ID by click on my readmore-link or getting the ID through my localize_script var.

Could somebody please help me?

**functions.php**

```
function get_extra_content() {
$content = array();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('page'),
    'p' => $post_id
);
$result = new WP_Query($args);
if ($result->have_posts()): while ($result->have_posts()) : $result->the_post();
    ...
endwhile; endif;
echo json_encode($content);
wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_extra_content', 'get_extra_content');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_extra_content', 'get_extra_content');
```

**ajax**

```
$('.morebtn').stop().click(function() {
    postID = $(this).data('postid');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        emptyReadMore();
        $(this).stop().toggleClass('active');
    }
    else {
        showReadMore(postID);
        $(this).stop().toggleClass('active');
    }
});

function showReadMore(postID) {

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_actions.ajaxurl, 
        dataType: 'json',  
        data: {
            action: "get_extra_content",
            post_id: postID //or ajax_actions.postid
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            ... 
        },
        complete: function(){
            ...     
        },
        success: function(data) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

**wp_localize_script**

```
global $post;
wp_register_script('scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js','','',true);
wp_localize_script('scripts', 'ajax_actions', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'postid' => $post->ID));
wp_enqueue_script('scripts');
```

Comment: Looking at your JS code, `$_GET['post_id']` can be used to get the post ID, i.e. `'p' => $_GET['post_id']` .. Or did I misread your question?

Comment: Sry, I dont know what you mean. Where to put what? $_GET['post_id'] neither works in functions.php nor in ajax..

Comment: you have to give it the post ID then read it in as a GET parameter, you're already doing this by sending `post_id` in the AJAX call, but then you're not reading it in and using it ( aka `$_GET['post_id']` ) PHP won't magically use it to create a `$page_id` variable! Think of it as if you're at a bakery, and you ask for bread, and the baker puts bread in their hand and reaches out towards you, and you ask "How do I get bread?", the answer is you pick up what's being handed to you. Also, I'm not sure. why you have `dataType: 'json',` in there, if you want to deal only in JSON use the REST API

Comment: Ah, ok. Now I got it. Thanks Sally and Tom!